# Firebase: difficulties manipulating data in a dynamic way

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have difficulties since few days doing what I would like to do on my web app (angular + firebase).

Here is one example (it's a chat room):

```
messages
    |__ 1
        |__ author: "foo"
        |__ message: "hello world"
        |__ playerExcluded: "foo2"
    |__ 2
        |__ author: "foo2"
        |__ message: "hello world"
        |__ playerExcluded: "foo"
```

I want to list all messages where currentUser != playerExluded (the user can see all messages except messages where he is excluded) and it must be dynamic.

I know it's not possible to do that with firebase database queries that's why I started looking at cloud functions but there is no trigger "on read".

Let's imagine it would be possible with queries, it will be something like:

```
firebase.database().ref('/messages').orderByChild('playerExcluded').differentTo(playerUsername)
```

Is there a way to do that with firebase (in dynamic manner)?

Comment: What I meant is all my calls to firebase.database are on my angular service (client side right?). I think I'm a bit confused about what user can do or not

Comment: What are you trying to say? Do you want to change your Firebase-Database dynamically according to the signed-in user? If yes, thats not possible

Comment: I don't want to change anything, I want to read something, in SQL it could be "SELECT * FROM MESSAGES WHERE PLAYEREXCLUDED != MYPLAYERUSERNAME

Comment: Where did you find differentTo method ? (doesn't exist it was an assumption in my post https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query). By safe way I think it's just a misunderstand from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found there is indeed no `onRead` database trigger for Cloud Functions. You could mimic the behavior by [building your own HTTPS function, which you then call from the app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

But note that the Admin SDK for the Realtime Database (which you use in Cloud Functions) also doesn't allow the query you're looking to make. So you'll still have to load all message and filter the excluded ones in code.

Answer (score 1):

You want to fetch all the messages where `playerExcluded != playerUsername`. So, I'm not providing you the whole code, but just the idea how you can get that done.

Firstly, retrieve the whole `messages` node by `listenerForSingleValueEvent`.

Then iterate through its children by `foreach loop`. And check if `playerExcluded` matches `playerUsername`, if so then ignore this one iteration by `continue`, and if not then save that in an `Array`.

At the end of the day, you will have an `Array` will all your required data.

Comment: Do you mean something like that: ref.on('value', (data) => {
        data.forEach( child => {
            if(child.val().playerExcluded != username) this.messages.push(child.val());
        })
    }); if i'm not wrong doing that will do the sort on client side, that means user can cheat and see the entire data